# Solving complex number equations

Tags: complex-numbers

I haven't been able to find any help about this and my math book is not helping at all. I need to solve this equation:

**z+1 = iz**

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you write it as $(i-1)z=1$, can you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $z=a+bi$ then we have for the equation.

$$a + bi + 1 -ai +b=0$$
$$(a+b+1) + (b-a)i=0$$

Now set $a+b+1=0$ and $a-b=0$ to get $a=b=-\frac 12$, hence $z = -\frac 12 - \frac i2$

Comment: I got the answer from the answer above but I want to be able to use this way as well. The only thing I don't understand is where the "i" goes in (a+bi+1). How does it become (a+b+1) ?

Comment: $bi$ goes in to the second term, or more precisely the first parenthesis contains the first, third and the last term of the upper equation.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $z(1-i) = -1 \to z = \dfrac{-1}{1-i}$. Can you take it further from here?

Comment: Yeah got it from that, thanks!